# How to write a long init in a webapp

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I use **glassfish** to run a webapp. I work with netbeans.

My webapp need a very long init.

I write that in a **ServletContextListener.contextInitialized** method.

I put in my code some logs.

If I write my init code inside the contextInitialized method, seems to me the init is interrupted by someone : the logs stop at a moment, I don't understand why.

If I write my code inside a sub thread, there no log at all.

What is the best way to do a long init in a webapp ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ServeletContextListener is the good place than the servlet init. Incase, for some reason(resource shortage or memory management issue) container destroys the servlet and recreates, then this may screw up the data for other servlets inside the same app.

Try to investigate the reason for the stoppage and keep ServletContextListner as is

Answer (score 0):

An option is to have a servlet [`load-on-startup`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039287). Make a servlet load on start-up like this

```
<web-app>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitProcess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.my.ServletName</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

</web-app>
```

The servlet will be loaded at start-up and `init()`, method of the Servlet will be called by the container. You may have your code there.

The number in `<load-on-startup>` decides the order in which servlets are loaded. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039287). This is supported by Tomcat and Weblogic, at least.

---

To get ServletContext use this:

```
 ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
```

See [this code block at Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/GetServletContextInitParameter.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why my code doesn't work ? In my contextInitialised method, I init some ServletContext attributes for my webapp, from the long init phase. Do you know how I can set them from a servlet ?

Comment: A servlet isn't really the right place for applicationwide init. This does also not answer the question why the servletcontextlistener init was apparently aborted.

Comment: @BalusC I agree with you. ContextListener is probably the right place. But it gives a lesser sophisticated alternative. As long as init abortion is concerned, I did not find enough detail. I think OP need to add more details (code snippet, stack-trace)